# sbt-protoc error File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, scalapb

I've scala grpc protobuf project with below `build.sbt`.

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val openRtbCoreVersion = "1.5.5"
val googleCommonProtosVersion = "1.12.0"

val commonSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq[Def.Setting[_]](
  scalaVersion := "2.12.14",
  organization := "com.td",
)

def scalaGrpcSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq[Def.Setting[_]](
  libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb"  %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion,
  libraryDependencies += "com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % googleCommonProtosVersion % "protobuf",

  PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
    PB.gens.java -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,
    scalapb.gen(javaConversions = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
  ),

  PB.includePaths in Compile := Seq(
    target.value / "protobuf_external",
),
  PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq(
    PB.externalIncludePath.value / "google" / "api",
    target.value / "protobuf_external",
    new File("definitions/common")
  ),

  PB.additionalDependencies := Nil
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "proto-path-error"
  ).settings(scalaGrpcSettings)
```

`project/plugins.sbt` file is -

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.20")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.10.0"
```

`project/build.properties` is -

```
sbt.version = 1.3.13
```

The `src/main/protobuf/definitions/common/common.proto` -

```
syntax = "proto2";

option java_outer_classname = "CommonUtils";
package com.td.protobuf;

message CMap {
    map<int32, Assets> cs  = 1;
}

message Assets {
    repeated int32 assets = 1;
}
```

The whole project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/proto-path-error)

This project is working fine. I want to update the `sbt-protoc` plugin in `project/plugins.sbt` to 1.0.0.

After I upgrade the sbt-protoc version to 1.0.0 I get below error when I do `sbt clean compile` -

> ```
>   /home/rajkumar/Coding/scala/proto-path-error/definitions/common/common.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
>   [error] java.lang.RuntimeException: protoc returned exit code: 1
>   [error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
>   [error]         at sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin$.compile(ProtocPlugin.scala:438)
>   [error]         at sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin$.compileProto$1(ProtocPlugin.scala:537)
>   [error]         at sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin$.$anonfun$sourceGeneratorTask$12(ProtocPlugin.scala:544)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$1(FileFunction.scala:73)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$4(FileFunction.scala:146)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:323)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:303)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$3(FileFunction.scala:142)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:323)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:298)
>   [error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$2(FileFunction.scala:141)
>   [error]         at sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin$.$anonfun$sourceGeneratorTask$4(ProtocPlugin.scala:549)
>   [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
>   [error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
>   [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
>   [error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
>   [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
>   [error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
>   [error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   [error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
>   [error] (Compile / protocGenerate) protoc returned exit code: 1
>   [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 9, 2022, 7:15:30 PM
> ```

what do I miss in the plugin upgrade. Any idea how can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things to fix in build.sbt to update for sbt-protoc 1.0.x. Perhaps it was relying on old behaviors that were fixed. Let's start first with the error that protoc is reporting:

```
File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  
You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the
proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too
dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are 
equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

In other words, every file we generate the sources for, need to be under "proto_path". ScalaPB takes cares of setting proto_path for you automatically, unless you somehow circumvent it by manually resetting it with `:=` like in here:

```
PB.includePaths in Compile := Seq(
    target.value / "protobuf_external",
),
```

And since `protobuf_external` is in the proto_path by default (also in older version), those lines are unnecessary and should be removed.

It appears that you want to unpack the protos that are in `proto-google-common-protos`. There's a shortcut for that: use `protobuf-src` instead of `protobuf` as the scope:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % googleCommonProtosVersion % "protobuf-src",
```

In summary, your config should be:

```
def scalaGrpcSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq[Def.Setting[_]](
  libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb"  %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion,
  libraryDependencies += "com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % googleCommonProtosVersion % "protobuf-src",
  PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
    PB.gens.java -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,
    scalapb.gen(javaConversions = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
  ),

  PB.protoSources in Compile ++= Seq(
    new File("definitions/common")
  )
)
```